# Backup and migrate exhausts memory

Tags: 8, backups

I have a new Drupal 8 site, where I installed few minor modules and Commerce 2.0 beta3, but the site has only 2 nodes so far, even the commerce tables are empty.

However even with PHP memory limit set to 2048M it exhausts it all giving me this message:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10464376 bytes) in /var/www/website/public_html/modules/backup_migrate/vendor/backupmigrate/core/src/Source/MySQLiSource.php on line 347
```

For this example the PHP memory limit was 1024M, I tried database only backup with cashe tables excluded.

I remember being able to run B&M with 256M allocation on D7 and hundreds of nodes, loads of modules and content types.

As I don't see this issue anywhere on the internet or reported as an issue on the module page, I'm left to believe there has to be something specific to what I may have done wrong?

In the log I also find the following (with full error reporting on):

```
Notice: Undefined index: settings_profile_id in Drupal\backup_migrate\Form\BackupMigrateQuickBackupForm->submitForm() (line 84 of /var/www/website/public_html/modules/backup_migrate/src/Form/BackupMigrateQuickBackupForm.php)
```

System specs:

> Ubuntu server 16.04
>
> Running Apache server
>
> With PHP7
>
> Drupal version 8.2.3

**EDIT:**

I found a few extra errors on different tests:

```
Notice: Undefined index: groups in BackupMigrate\Drupal\Config\DrupalConfigHelper::addFieldsFromSchema() (line 91 of /var/www/website/public_html/modules/backup_migrate/src/Config/DrupalConfigHelper.php)

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in BackupMigrate\Drupal\Config\DrupalConfigHelper::addFieldsFromSchema() (line 91 of /var/www/website/public_html/modules/backup_migrate/src/Config/DrupalConfigHelper.php)

Notice: Undefined index: #description in BackupMigrate\Drupal\Config\DrupalConfigHelper::addFieldsFromSchema() (line 116 of /var/www/website/public_html/modules/backup_migrate/src/Config/DrupalConfigHelper.php)
```

Where the last one appears twice in a row every error sequence.

Appreciate all help!

Alari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reduce the memory exhaustion with remedying the last edit's errors in the following matter:

I added a not empty check for the "groups" index in the array around the foreach function on the 91-st line of code in DrupalConfigHelper.php

```
static public function addFieldsFromSchema(&$form, $schema, ConfigInterface $config, $parents = []) {
// Add the specified groups.
// Temp fix for "Undefined index: groups..."
if(isset($schema['groups']) && !empty($schema['groups'])){
  foreach ($schema['groups'] as $group_key => $item) {
    // If the group is just called 'default' then use the key from the plugin as the group key.
    // @TODO: make this less ugly.
    if ($group_key == 'default' && $parents) {
      $group_key = end($parents);
    }
    if (!isset($form[$group_key])) {
      $form[$group_key] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => $item['title'],
        '#tree' => FALSE,
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

And fixed the "undefined index #description" error on line 116 by checking if the "#description" index exists, and if not create it with empty value to be processed on the initial 116 line.

```
switch ($item['type']) {
    case 'text':
      $form_item['#type'] = 'textfield';
      if (!empty($item['multiple'])) {
        $form_item['#type'] = 'textarea';
        // Temp fix for "Undefined index #description..."
        if (!isset($form_item['##description'])) {
          $form_item['##description'] = '';
        }
        $form_item['#description'] .= ' ' . t('Add one item per line.');
        $form_item['#element_validate'] = ['BackupMigrate\Drupal\Config\DrupalConfigHelper::validateMultiText'];
        $value  = implode("\n", $value);
      }
      if (!empty($item['multiline'])) {
        $form_item['#type'] = 'textarea';
      }
...
```

Now backup works nicely.